# "undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass" Rails Guides Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on RailsGuides Tutorial (creating a blog app). When I run server and open: `/posts/new` everything looks fine. But, when I try to create a post I get this error:

> NoMethodError in Posts#show
>
> Showing /home/darek/rails_projects/blog/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #3 
>   raised:
>
> undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #3):

```
1  <p>
2  <strong>Title:</strong>
3  <%= @post.title %>
4  </p>
5  <p>
```

In fact post is created, and I can see title and content at /posts
But when I try to use show specific post I get this error. 
My first clue was to change line

```
<%= @post.title %>
```

to

```
<%= @post.try(:title) %>
```

Error is gone, but problem isn't solved.
When I try to show specific post I get Title, and Text forms empty. It is not what I want to see ;)

Ok, here is the code

Show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @post.text %>
</p>


<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
 <% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back to Posts', posts_path %>
```

Posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def new 
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

  if @post.save
  redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private
  def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

   def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   end

   def edit
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   end

    def update
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])

      if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
        redirect_to @post
      else 
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @post.destroy

      redirect_to posts_path
    end
end
```

Rake Routes:

```
-VirtualBox:~/rails_projects/blog$ rake routes
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
    post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
         new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
        edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
             post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
             root GET    /                                           welcome#index
                  GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#view
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
```

Thanks for help and interest!

Comment: Whitespace matters in Ruby! Is this line indented properly in your source code? `@post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))`? `redirect_to @post` and `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)` also are not properly indented.

Comment: sorry @André Dion.. but it doesn't matters. but yes it looks clean, if properly indented.

Comment: Do your @post object contains title or not?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

you have made your methods private. Remember where you put private keyword. all the methods below that, will become private, define your methods like this. private methods in end of the controller :

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def new 
  @post = Post.new
end

def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def create
@post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
    redirect_to @post
  else 
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy

  redirect_to posts_path
end



private
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
 end

end
```

Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: This is really useful for newbies in Rails. Thank you

Comment: +1 for **Remember where you put private keyword. all the methods below that, will become private**

Comment: Thank you! Author of the tutorial must have glazed over that fact.

Comment: +1! I assumed that the private would only be making the next section private. Not everything under it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I met the same problem as you when following the tutorial. And I checked my codes again then found the reason. In the **posts_controller.rb** file, you cannot put the private method in the middle of the codes, that means all the methods below (such as show, edit) will be private. Instead, put the private method at the bottom like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end
    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    end
    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
    private
        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
        end
end
```

Hope to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was not writing this line below the class definition (maps_controller):

```
    class MapsController < ApplicationController
     before_action :set_map, only: [:show, :edit, :update,:destroy]
     ...
    end
```

Map is my model, after writing that line, My view worked.  Be careful in not to put public code below private methods.

Answer (score 1):

I have meet this problem to . I have checked all the process and code, all is as same as the tutorial. 
In the end, in the terminal I run:

```
rake db:drop,    
rake db:create,    
rake db:migrate
```

then restart the server, reopen the localhost:3000

solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial has a typo then, because I followed these same steps and resolved the same issue. However, I was following the tutorial

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was only solved by re-executing bin/rake routes after creating show.html.erb. The instructions called to do this earlier, but re-doing it immediately solved the problem without changing anything else (since my private was the final thing in my file and I was still receiving this error).

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into same error for the same tutorial, and es already rails experts have already answered the question technically. 
but i just wanted to say that first complete one video to understand the concept and then second time try to create with him.

for above issue the **author gives the solution in same video**, In fact he shows us this error in the video with explanation and solution(as ou might already have know now but I am answering for someone like me who will **visit this question first time**). Its ok to panic at this stage as we all are new but lets first understand the concepts in a video and then do the hands on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this was the first post that showed up when googling the issue so I wanted to help out others that found their way to this thread.

I found yet another way to fix the problem, I changed the private keyword to public in the articles_controller.rb, saved it and went to http://localhost:3000/articles/new
and created a new article.

When I hit save article it showed up the way it was supposed to, then I went back and changed the keyword to private and saved articles_controller.rb, and it still let me create a new article a second time but this time the method was private.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart rails server.

```
rails restart
```