# Can't access data for posts in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I was working on this rails tutorial: "http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html" and than I got to the part that you are supposed to show the title and data for an individual post (5.7) and got an error when it was supposed to show the data, so I put `@post.inspect` into /app/views/posts/show.html.erb and I got nil, and same with the index page where it lists all of the posts, but I checked and the data is in the database correctly. Here's my controller file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params.permit(:title, :text))

  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end


private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
end
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#show
Showing /home/hiram/rails/meme/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):
1 <p>
2 <strong>Title:</strong>
3 <%= @post.title %>
4 </p>
5
6 <p>

Rails.root: /home/hiram/rails/meme
```

Comment: "and got an error when it was supposed to show the data" What error did you get?

Comment: `NoMethodError in Posts#show
Showing /home/hiram/rails/blog/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):
1
2
3
4
5
6
          
  <p>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <%= @post.title %>
  </p>
  
  <p>

Rails.root: /home/hiram/rails/blog`

Comment: What url are you hitting?  http://localhost/posts/1 ?

Comment: http://www.hiram.flfn.org:3000/posts/1

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
```

to end of file

["undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass" Rails Guides Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810348/undefined-method-title-for-nilnilclass-rails-guides-tutoraial/17810507#17810507)